# Why are the state/css transition times not identical for this simple slider made with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I made a functional demo sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-knuth-f0xpj)

This is a basic array cycler with 3 elements. And these 3 elements are rendered as slides which move visually left/right depending on the direction you pick.

I don't think the approach I took to make this work is a good one, and if you have suggestions on that I'm open to it.

But the actual question, in order to make the sliding work "equivalently" in both direction i.e. left/right I had to delay the one "sliding" to the left. My naming convention is kind of confusing too because you click the button e.g. prev/next and the array cycling/sliding is flipped. I did use an anti-pattern with the external variable that holds the direction selected since I was having problems with multiple states affecting the slider/causing rendering issues.

But TL:DR this is the `onClick` handler for the prev/next buttons passing in boolean for direction.I'm using a CSS animation for the motion part. I'm also aware nested ternaries are bad.

```
const cycleArr = cyclePrev => {
    if (!slideDone) {
      return;
    }
    setSlideDone(false);
    const newArrSort = cyclePrev ? cycleLeft(slides) : cycleRight(slides);
    slideClassRef.current.classList = slideDir
      ? `App ${slideDir === "left" ? "slide-left" : "slide-right"}`
      : "App";
    if (slideDir === "left") {
      setSlides(newArrSort);
      setTimeout(() => {
        slideClassRef.current.classList = "App";
        setSlideDone(true);
      }, 1050);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        slideClassRef.current.classList = "App";
        setSlides(newArrSort);
        setSlideDone(true);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
```

I'm aware I could have just used something off the shelf eg. slick carousel but this is a good demo of my current problems with state planning in ReactJS. I'm trying to get better/think better at it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, if you are referring to the additional 50ms delay when sliding, my best guess is that the call to `setSlides(newArrSort);` sets the state and also triggers an immediate React re-render of the component. This probably takes some amount of time, hence the desynchronisation with the CSS transition.

Anti-patterns are not there to make your life difficult, they are there to stop you getting into a confusing mess :)

Components can re-render whenever React deems it necessary, which is why state should be properly stored, and pretty effects done in useEffect hooks. I would recommend a more React-based data flow, where you update the state at the top, and let it propagate downwards, reacting to the new state, applying the correct CSS transformations. It's declarative, like HTML and CSS. You don't tell the browser what to paint, you describe how to paint it.

Comment: Yeah my question primarily is why they're not both 1050 or 1000, it is slower/has a problem one direction than the other. And then generally I was hoping someone would tell me "don't build this like this, do it like this" but I don't know if SO is a code review place haha, probably not. -- like your last suggestion there, that's what I'm looking for, so I can build stuff better next time.

Comment: Also the reason I used the external state is because when I update the array and the slide direction I get problems where the render occurs twice. I did  try to combine the states and I still had problems where the data switching/sliding clashed.

Comment: There are too many questions to get decent answers,
The reason you are getting double renders might be due to the fact you are running React under StrictMode, it does this double rendering in development .
Also, modifying DOM nodes directly is asking for trouble. Try to let React add the classes (instead of using refs), you'll have a better idea of when the animation starts as well. Update state -> rerender -> dynamic className + setTimeout in useEffect that reorders slides and sets as done -> rerender with correct slides, react will update the DOM.

Comment: My initial approach did have a css slide class state that was passed down into a dynamically rendered slide, but that's the issue is I'd have two triggers on the re-render, the array cycling and the sliding... anyway I'll think about it more. The strict mode is interesting, I just saw that appear recently/have seen it in some node projects too not entirely sure what it's for.